# ToolStripMenuItem Sub items are cut off

Tags: vb.net

[image]

```
    Dim cms As New ContextMenuStrip
    Dim toolstripMenu As New ToolStripMenuItem("Sub Menu")

    With toolstripMenu.DropDownItems
        .Add(menuitem1BTN)
        .Add(menuitem2BTN)
        .Add(menuitem3BTN)
    End With

    With cms.Items
        .Add(toolstripMenu)
    End With


    mainNI.ContextMenuStrip = cms
```

`mainNI` is a NotifyIcon. `cms` is the primary `ContextMenuStrip`, attached to `mainNI`. `toolstripMenu` is the "submenu" of `cms`. `cms` appears normally.

As you can see in the picture, my menu items are getting cut off. It doesn't matter if I force resize the `ToolStripMenuItem` or set it to `AutoSize`. I can confirm on `Opening` event that the size of the `ToolStripMenuItem` is double the width of any item on the strip.

Comment: what is `mainNI` that the menu is attached to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: mainNI is NotifyIcon. @HansPassant instead of telling how to ask a question, tell me what you think I'm missing.

Comment: What is the width in the `Opened` event?

Comment: I had an `Opened` event as a test. I set it to 200 for fun, and it had no effect. Again, the width is at least double of any button on the strip. I took a screenshot of the menu (and cropped it), and determined it is 84 wide by 158 high.

Comment: 1. generate the menu in the designer 2. check the generated code in the .Designer.vb file 3. ???? 4. PROFIT!!!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Slai, I created the menu in the Designer. I duplicated the error by opening a new project. I discovered the Designer uses `ToolStripMenuItem`. I used `ToolStripButton`. This reminds me of a question on SO of someone with this same problem, but `ToolStripLabel`. Perhaps this is a bug.